# PHP Reload Time

Tags: php, google-chrome, web

Hello I have a Problem with my PHP. Im coding in two ways:

1. I upload a File to my FTP Sever
2. Save it Local and run it with MAMP (OSX)

But in both ways i save/upload the new file but it takes about 2-5 Min until i can see the changes.

Example:

Old PHP:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

New PHP:

```
<?php
echo "test2";
?>
```

So i save the second file but until i see the second text it may taxes aboout 2-5 Minutes?

Can i change something in my PHP Info file or something else ? Or is there another way to code in PHP ?

Comment: Is this due to browser side caching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a caching problem. Try hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd><sup>*</sup> and see if the changes are instant then. If that's the problem, [**see this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690269/disabling-chrome-cache-for-website-development) for how to disable the cache to prevent this problem.

Also, as loveNoHate points out in the comments, it is possible that this is a server- or ISP-side caching problem.  Because you have the same problem running it locally on `MAMP`, however, it sounds like a browser issue.

<sup>* The Mac OS X shortcut. For future visitors: you would use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> for Windows.</sup>

Comment: If the problem persists on your server then, you have a caching with your ISP, ask them what to do. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since this is mac you might want to do

For Safari: <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to clear cache and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to refresh

For Chrome: hold down <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> key and then press <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it doesn't explain to the user what the problem is (caching). +1 if it is clarified.

Comment: Well, the caching could be anywhere upstream, could be the browser, the ISP, could be a cache plugin, could be the cache ninjas out to take over the world...you never know :)

Comment: True. It's just that caching is incredibly confusing for new developers (and not easy to figure out for old hands, either). +1 anyway for "cache ninjas out to take over the world" - that pushed me over the line. :)